# Fill na in columns but sorted by name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe consisting of rows starting with the Name of the participant and then a lot of columns with information. Each person can have up to 500 rows.

In the columns some data is personal data, for example the gender or preferable jumping leg. This will be the same number in all rows depending on the person's name.

Is there a possibility to fill the nan based on if it is the same name?

[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible, but please provide an explicit **reproducible** example for clarity

Comment: I can not make it more clear because of privacy

Comment: Well, you can certainly craft a dummy example… sorry but without clarity your question should probably be closed

Comment: i added a small picture of how it looks like

Comment: Ok, I see, it is not always the first column which is filled and there is the possibility, that more than one row is filled. Is it possible that there are filled rows with **different** values? If this is possible, how should these cases be handled? (e.g. in case person B has gender 2 and 3)

Comment: If all the missing values should be filled and there are no different values per person, wouldn't that create lots of duplicates? Is that your goal?

Comment: Is **at least** one row per person filled completely?

Comment: There are no different values per person. It does indeed create a lot of duplicates but there are way more variables with different values all the time. There is at least one row per person completely filled but it is not always the first one

Comment: I see. This is a little different from your initial quesiton. Let me change my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two-step approach:

1. Ignoring the metrics, the code removes duplicates, so that you get all characteristics for each person, but only one row per person.
2. Delete the current characteristics and replace them with the complete characteristics. The `merge()` performs a join which brings the duplicated characteristics back.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# specify which columns are characteristics and which are metrics
characteristics = ['characteristic_1', 'characteristic_2']
metrics = ['metric_1', 'metric_2']

# create a sample dataframe with missing characteristics
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane'],
                   'characteristic_1': [None, 'Male', 'Female', None, 'Female'],
                   'characteristic_2': [5.5, None, 5.6, 5.5, None],
                   'metric_1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                   'metric_2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})

# Step 1: Group by name and fill missing characteristics
df_filled_characteristics = df.groupby('name')[characteristics].first().reset_index()

# Step 2: Drop the characteristics from the original dataframe and join the filled characteristics
df_final = df.drop(characteristics, axis=1).merge(df_filled_characteristics, on='name')

# Output the final dataframe
print(df_final)
```

Don't be confused by the `first()`, it uses the first non-NaN (i.e. filled) value.

Comment: @EJagerde Is tis what you were looking for?

Comment: Thankyou, but i am not 100% sure that all the first rows are filled. That is the problem

Comment: @EJagerde Can you describe in your own words how you would identify them? Like which rules as a human would you follow?

Comment: I dont understand your question. I added a small picture of how the dataframe looks like, if that is what you are asking?

Comment: @EJagerde I hope I understood you correctly this time?

Comment: thankyou! I will have a look at it by the end of the week and see if it works